# Show Coverage Data for one method in Intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

Is there a way I can generate the coverage data for just one method ? I have a couple of tests for a class, but I would like to see the coverage percentage for just one of the methods from that class (how many lines of that particular method were covered). Currently it will only show me the coverage of the package or of the class.

Thank you!

Edit: Or perhaps test only one method? 
Caution: I am not referring to running only one test method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run only one test from the class, and it will show you coverage of that test.

After that you could run another test and "add" the coverage. Or you could not add it to coverage suite and see coverage for only that test.